# Login into Clients server with theire rsa key

Tags: ssh, openssh

A client gave me a rsa and ppk file so I can log into their server. Im using OSX Lion and I have all my current server connections in my id_rsa file. How do I add their key so I can login with that?

Comment: the answer below is the way to go. But if you want something quicker: ssh IP_OR_HOSTNAME -i PATH_TO_KEY_FILE

Answer (score 2):

If the RSA file they gave you is stored in, say, `~/client/foo_rsa.key`, you could:

```
$ ssh -i ~/client/foo_rsa.key username@theirhost.example.com
```

Storing this sort of configuration in `~/.ssh/config` is also a very good idea if you want a more permanent solution.

In `~/.ssh/config`, add:

```
host clienthost
    identityfile  client/foo_rsa.key
    hostname      theirhost.example.com
    user          usernameonhost
```

You then connect simply with:

```
$ ssh clienthost
```

and the settings from the config file control your session.

The spacing above is unimportant and included only for readabilty.  Read `man ssh_config` for details of other things you can put in this configuration file.  There's A LOT of stuff you can do, including proxying your connection through other hosts, creating encrypted tunnels (for other protocols like HTTP or SOCKS) on arbitrary ports, etc.